# Edit (Find and Replace) .ini File with Batch

Tags: batch-file, edit, ini

I have searched for an answer to this question and I haven't understood the solution. I am trying to do a find and replace on a .ini file using batch. What Im trying to do exactly is edit php.ini and find all instances of the string "5.4.3" and replace it with "5.6.14".

I was trying to use this based on an answer I saw on stack overflow:

```
`set "file=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.14\php.ini"
:loop
findstr %old% "%file%" >nul || (
type "%file%"|repl "5.4.3" "5.6.14" >"%file%.tmp"
move "%file%.tmp" "%file%" >nul
)
ping -n 120 localhost >nul
goto :loop`
```

The execution hangs and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `repl` is not a valid batch command. It is [its own separate batch script](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855) that you need to have in the same directory as your script.

Comment: Repl.bat was depracated a long time ago. The new version is called JREPL and can be found here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Comment: 1. what is `%old%` set to?? 2. I guess execution does not really "hang", you wrote an indefinite loop by `goto :loop`...

Comment: old is set to the string "php5.4.3"

Comment: Now I am trying to use JRepl.bat by using: jrepl "\bphp5.4.3\b" "php5.6.14" /f php.ini /o -                                             But this does not seem to be working!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot add anything (such a jrepl.bat) to the machine, you can do it yourself by using string replacement. I am not suggesting against jrepl.bat. The works of dbenham are usually very good.

```
=== repit.bat

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "THEFILE=C:\Users\pwatson\y\log.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s in (`TYPE "%THEFILE%"`) DO (
    SET THESTRING=%%s
    ECHO !THESTRING:5.4.3=5.6.14!
)

EXIT /B
```

If you want to save this into a new file, use redirection.

```
CALL repit.bat >log.txt.new
```

Comment: This is what I am trying based on your response, Im sure im doing something wrong but this isnt working for me:
`
    SET "THEFILE=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.14\php.ini"

    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s in (`TYPE "%THEFILE%"`) DO (
        SET THESTRING=%%s
        ECHO !THESTRING:5.4.3=5.6.14!
    )`

Comment: In what way is it "not working?" Is there an error message? Be sure to redirect the output of this script to a new file. `CALL CHANGEM.BAT >newphp.ini` Are you wanting the script to go ahead and replace the original file?